# Setting a Windows environment variable to be read by a Ruby script

Tags: ruby, windows, environment-variables

My setup: Windows 7, ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

In scratchfile.rb, I have:

```
puts ENV["TESTVAR"]
```

At my command prompt, I type:

```
set TESTVAR = hello
ruby scratchfile.rb
```

I get the following output:

```
C:\myrubyproject>
```

Why don't I see the value 'hello'? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put spaces around `=`.

```
> set TESTVAR=hello
> ruby -e 'p ENV["TESTVAR"]'
"hello"
```